# How to calculate power in Cochran's Q test

Tags: statistical-power, cochran-q

I want to know how to calculate power in Cochran’s Q test. I performed an experiment designed within-participants. Participants respond to one question in each three conditions. The number of participants is 54. The result showed a significant difference between the conditions (Q(2)=11.8, p <.01). However, reviewers asked me to analysis the power of the experiment to evaluate whether the sample size was valid. I know the result of post-hoc power analysis should be interpreted carefully, but I need to know the power value. Would you tell me the way to calculate the power in Cochran’s Q test?